# define onPostExecute when new Asynctask is called

Tags: java, android, interface, abstract-class

i created a class extending `Asynctask`. This class is called from multiple Activities. It gets some data from a webpage. After that, depending on the url, the data is processed in the `onPostExecute` method. Right now im using multiple `else if` statements but its a bit unhandy.

Is there a way to define the `onPostExecute` method in the Activity that creates the new `Asynctask`.

I think it might work with an interface or an abstract method but am not sure and dont know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You register an event listener for the AsyncTask that it will call when `onPostExecute` runs.

```
public class Example extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  public interface ExampleListener {
    public void onStart();
    public void onProgress();
    public void onFinish();
  }

  private ExampleListener listener;

  public Example(ExampleListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPreExecute() {
    ...
    mListener.onStart();
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onProgressUpdate(Void... v) {
    ...
    mListener.onProgress();
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    ...
    mListener.onFinish();
    ...
  }
}
```

Customize the pattern to fit whatever design you need. Include whatever parameters to the interface methods the listener needs to have for each event.  If you have a class that implements `Example.ExampleListener`, then you need only start this by calling `new Example(this).execute()`.

Comment: i tried that but get a nullpointerexception when listener.onFinish() is called. but i initialized the listener in the constructor

Comment: Are you getting the nullPointerException in the method `onFinish()` or when you call `onFinish()`?

Comment: when i call onFinish(). seems like listener equals null

Answer (score 6):

You can do it without any extra work.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        // do some work
        return null;
    }

}
```

And in the Activity:

```
MyTask t = new MyTask()
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // do some work             
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, more java/generic, that could help improve your code would be to use [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.
In short, for each different data processing you would create a different class that is implementing the same interface. In that way adding new "strategies" would need to need new classes so your code would be clear.
Example:

```
 public void onPostExecute(String result){
ResponParser responseParser;

if (result.equals("http://..1"));
responseParser = new ResponParser1();
else if (result.equals("http://..2"));
responseParser = new ResponParser1();

responseParser.parse();
}
```

where ResponParser is an interface implemented by both ResponParser1 and ResponParser1 which are concrete classes.

Answer (score -1):

Using an interface is the best option but for simplicity you can also pass a Runnable to AsyncTask which you can execute in onPostExecute() method.